# Telnet : How to get [user@hostname userFolder]$

Tags: linux, ubuntu, path, telnet, client-server

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 LTS and i have successfully configured a telnet server. 
When i logging into telnet server i always get the path(int the terminal) as

> username@hostname:~/Folder_Name$

I really want to know when do i get the path like this ,

> [username@hostname Folder_Name]$

Comment: Duplicate of quite a few "how do I customize my shell prompt" questions.

Comment: @grawity well he may kind of be asking what setups if any would have that by default 'cos he claims to have seen it. He asked when does he get XYZ.  (though people have answered the question of how can be customize it to have XYZ)

Comment: Do you mean that you have seen that sometimes it has square brackets and sometimes not?  (and you want to know when it would and when it wouldn't?).

Comment: [Don't](https://catn.com/2010/03/23/why-do-we-use-ssh-over-telnet/) [use](http://www.linuxcertified.com/e-learning/linuxplus/html/4_11_1.html) [telnet](http://www.spy-hill.net/myers/help/SecureShell.html); [use](http://www.scrounge.org/linux/ssh.html) [ssh](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/replace-telnet-with-ssh-to-shore-up-secure-connections/) [instead](http://gotoanswer.com/?q=Why+you+should+use+ssh+instead+of+telnet.).

Comment: @BlacklightShining I'm creating one.

Comment: You're making a what?

Comment: @BlacklightShining ssh server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latter prompt that you have seen is the default on Red Hat-based systems, such as Red Hat Enterprise Linux, CentOS, and Fedora. The former is the default on Debian-based systems such as Debian itself and Ubuntu.

The default Red Hat PS1 prompt is:

```
export PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$ "
```

You can of course change the prompt to whatever you wish. I prefer the Red Hat-style but with the complete path shown instead of simply the last directory component.

```
export PS1="[\u@\h \w]\\$ "
```

And of course you should never be using telnet on *anything*, but using ssh instead.

Comment: +1 this is a proper answer , answering both interpretations of his question in one. Though he wants capital W (just the last directory). And it'd be good to paste `echo $PS1` on a red hat based system, as a kind of proof, and the prompt.

Comment: He wants capital W, perhaps, but I don't. I did mention why, too. :)

Comment: what if you have a really long path following the host, like `user@computerxyz ~/fon/topics/Computer Articles/software documents/android studio notes/ $`  wouldn't you want a new line at the end of it?

Comment: You can if you want. My prompt on my desktop does. But paths rarely get that long on servers I manage, so it isn't much of an issue there.

Comment: Are there any distros, if not now then years ago, where the default  is/was that they didn't even show the last directory. i.e. just $ or user@host $ ?

Comment: @barlop Back in the olden days, `$ ` was all we got.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22996/discussion-between-barlop-and-michael-hampton).

Answer (score 2):

That’s pretty easy. Just look at [`man 1 bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash): Whereas the default prompt uses `\w` (“the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde (uses the value of the PROMPT_DIRTRIM variable)”), there’s also `\W`: “the basename of the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde”

To get what you want, use this:

```
export PS1="[\u@\h \W]$ "
```

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question of where he would've seen it with square brackets

Comment: @barlop See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/903428/telnet-how-to-get-userhostname-userfolder#comment1212465_903435)

Answer (score 2):

What you're after is the bash PS1 variable. To get what you want, you need to export this variable from `.bashrc`, which is executed on login.

The PS1 you want should look like this:

`export PS1="[\u@\h \W]$ "`

place that in `.bashrc` in your home directory. Or just run it as a command from the shell if you want it just temporarily.

If you want colors on there, here's the one that I've used for years, slightly modified to suit your question:

```
export PS1='[\[\033[1;33m\]\u\[\033[1;35m\]@\[\033[1;32m\]\h\[\033[0;36m\]\W\[\033[1;37m\]]\$ \[\033[0;37m\]'
```

***Disclaimer:*** Everyone but me thinks the above is ugly.

---

On a related note: You should avoid telnetting into your machine, as telnet is very insecure. I highly recommend using ssh instead.

Comment: ok but would he ever get it without customizing it himself. Does it ever produce that natively?  I doubt the questioner has actually customized it though he has seen it before

Comment: @barlop Yes, by using an upper case `\W`

Comment: good point re upper case W to get the last directory only. But re square brackets, maybe more like `export PS1="[\u@\h \]\W]$ "` to get his square brackets in. But it doesn't answer the question of where he would have seen it with the square brackets.  With your customization, when would he see it with square brackets ever? And adapting yours to include squrae brackets, he'd see them every time.

Comment: @barlop didn't notice the brackets, thanks. Added them

Comment: So with that customization he has that prompt always, but note what he asked in his question. "I really want to know when do i get the path like this ,"  <-- see. Now, with your customization, he gets it Always. But clearly he gets them sometimes and not others, or he has seen it sometimes and when he hasn't customized it. So the question is - when.

Comment: @barlop The question is not really stated clearly. But the simplest answer would be: `Q: When do I get the prompt like this? Answer: When customizing the prompt yourself like in this answer.`. :) He also states he always gets the prompt like the first one. Not that he sometimes gets it like the second. Maybe he's seen it somewhere on another system and wants it like that. (Again. The question is stated poorly).

Comment: `$PS1` doesn't need to be _exported._

Comment: @BlacklightShining well what command do you use besides export PS1=".."?

Comment: @barlop You can simply do `PS1="[\u@\h \W]\$ "` (variable assignments aren't commands in shell scripting).

Comment: @barlop Neither of the two currently-approved edits change that part of the asker's phrasing. Until **they** (gender was not stated!) reply to [your comment](https://superuser.com/q/903428/#comment1212127_903428) or edit the question to clarify, myself and many others will continue to assume that they're asking how to customize their prompt. The question might also be closed as too unclear or possibly as a duplicate.

Comment: @BlacklightShining  I suggest giving the questioner time to come back.  I think the questioner may well be interested in how to customize the prompt, but if he never intended to even mean the other interpretation, and isn't willing to ask the other interpretation(i.e. he insists his question is a how to customize the prompt), then it should be closed.

Comment: @barlop I think it should be put on hold immediately: it's unclear as currently worded. It can be resumed once the asker comes back and edits it.

Comment: @barlop I had problems with my internet connection so i couldn't reply .I saw this in our computer lab a year ago .We were using telnet there .The question came when i tried to create a telnet server my own. Since i had left that institution ,i have no longer access to that lab that's why i asked this question.

Comment: @BlacklightShining Sorry for such a delay in replying. I never want to customize but i wanted to know when do i get it like this : [username@hostname Folder_Name]$ .The idea of customizing came only when one user posted an answer .Unfortunately that answer was not clear and I think the user had deleted the answer.

Comment: The problem lies with your phrasing, which you've just repeated there: _when do I get it like this?_ Are you asking how to configure your current shell to prompt like that, or are you asking what shell prompts like that by default, or under what conditions a shell would prompt like that?

Comment: @BlacklightShining Sorry , I asked how it appeared like that by default.

Comment: Edit that information into your question.